# Getting first value from map in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm using `map` in C++.  Suppose I have 10 values in the `map` and I want only the first one. How do I get it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

A map will not keep insertion order. Use `*(myMap.begin())` to get the value of the first pair (the one with the smallest key when ordered).

You could also do `myMap.begin()->first` to get the key and `myMap.begin()->second` to get the value.

Comment: `myMap.begin()` returns an iterator. You might want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: No, it returns values. `myMap.begin()` is an iterator, which has the `*` and `->` operators overloaded to behave like a pointer and the `++` and `--` operators overloaded to iterate elements in your map. You should read an introduction about the STL. Maybe someone has a good link for you?

Comment: and if i want the value and not the iterator?

Comment: @adir: it's explained in the last paragraph.

Comment: @Benoit Do you have any idea about the type of first ,second in map? Thanks

Answer (score 20):

As simple as:

```
your_map.begin()->first // key
your_map.begin()->second // value
```

Answer (score 7):

`begin()` returns the first pair, (precisely, an iterator to the first pair, and you can access the key/value as `->first` and `->second` of that iterator)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the iterator that is returned by the begin() method of the map template:

```
std::map<K, V> myMap;
std::pair<K, V> firstEntry = *myMap.begin()
```

But remember that the std::map container stores its content in an ordered way. So the first entry is not always the first entry that has been added.

Comment: Quite the opposite: It stores its content in an ordered fashion, based on comparisons of the keys!

Comment: Yes folks, you are absolutely right. It is ordered by key order. What I meant to say is, that the order of insertion is not preserved, i.e. the first added entry to the map is not neccessarily the one at **begin()**.

Answer (score 0):

`*my_map.begin()`.  See e.g. http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/begin/.